# Why is the stream identifier 31 bit in HTTP/2 and why is it preceded with a reserved bit?

Tags: http2

The frame format in HTTP/2 looks like this (source: [HTTP/2: Frame Format](http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#FrameHeader)):

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                 Length (24)                   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Type (8)    |   Flags (8)   |
+-+-------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
|R|                 Stream Identifier (31)                      |
+=+=============================================================+
|                   Frame Payload (0...)                      ...
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

> **R**:
> A reserved 1-bit field. The semantics of this bit are undefined, and the bit MUST remain unset (0x0) when sending and MUST be ignored when receiving.
>
> **Stream Indentifier:** A stream identifier (see [Section 5.1.1](http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#StreamIdentifiers)) expressed as an unsigned 31-bit integer. The value 0x0 is reserved for frames that are associated with the connection as a whole as opposed to an individual stream.

Is there a reason why they did not use a 32-bit unsigned integer? And why specifying that a reserved bit has to be set to 0 and must be ignored by the receiver?

Is it just a concession to languages like Java, which do not have a 32-bit unsigned integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discussed here: https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/issues/67

> Purpose is for experimentation with stream reprioritization.
>
> http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2013AprJun/0135.html
>
> Also there to protect against some implementations having problems
> with signed vs. unsigned
>
> Discussed in Hamburg; are a variety of use cases, no need to remove
> (now).

Comment: "implementations having problems with signed vs. unsigned" is fancy wording for "Java has no unsigned 32bit integer"