# HTTP2 max window size

Tags: http, standards, specifications, http2

HTTP2 specification clearly states that:

> Values above the maximum flow-control window size of (2^31)-1 MUST be treated as a connection error of type `FLOW_CONTROL_ERROR`.

What is the rationale for this hard limit? What does the limit accomplish? What potential problems is the specification trying to solve by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a concession to languages (like Java) that have signed and unsigned bits so only have 31 bits to play with for integers. Similar to this: [Why is the stream identifier 31 bit in HTTP/2 and why is it preceded with a reserved bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309442/why-is-the-stream-identifier-31-bit-in-http-2-and-why-is-it-preceded-with-a-rese)